# APT tries to configure PostgreSQL each time I try to install a package

Tags: apt, postgresql

I'm getting some strange errors lately whenever trying to apt-get install anything.  Here's an example from trying to install fluidsynth.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libfluidsynth1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libfluidsynth1 is already the newest version.
libfluidsynth1 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up postgresql-9.1 (9.1.10-0ubuntu12.04) ...
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                                     * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-11-03 14:21:42 EST FATAL:  could not access private key file "server.key": No such file or directory
                                                                                                                                                       [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing postgresql-9.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql:
 postgresql depends on postgresql-9.1; however:
  Package postgresql-9.1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postgresql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-9.1
 postgresql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm running 12.04.  What's causing this and how do I address it?  It happens for installing lots of things, and seems to suggest I need to initialize postgresql or something.  I don't recall having fiddled with postgres, so I'm not sure why this suddenly became problematic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove/purge `postgresql-9.1` and reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove postgresql-9.1 postgresql
```

If you really use postgresql, or another package depends of it, you can install it again

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql the-other-program-that-got-removed
```

BTW, `libfluidsynth1` is already installed, you don't need to install it again.

Comment: `(Reading database ... 1024332 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postgresql ...
Removing postgresql-9.1 ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                                                                                             [ OK ] 
Purging configuration files for postgresql-9.1 ...
Dropping cluster main...
dpkg: warning: while removing postgresql-9.1, directory '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib' not empty so not removed.
`

Comment: I don't see any problem there? What is the problem? You need `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib` empty. Just run `sudo rm /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/*`

Answer (score 0):

There's an even easier solution:  Postgresql requires the "snakeoil" certificate to exist in order to run: /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key  If this was somehow deleted from your system, you can generate a new one with

```
# make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil
```